# date diff with max in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Following query has group by clause error. I do not know how to make it correct

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(updated_date), DATEDIFF(NOW(),MAX(updated_date))
FROM `authentication`
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),MAX(updated_date)) > 20
GROUP by user_id
```

Comment: Please include the error in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want a `having` clause:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(updated_date), 
       DATEDIFF(NOW(), MAX(updated_date)) as diff
FROM `authentication`
GROUP by user_id
HAVING diff > 20
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do `MAX()` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(updated_date), DATEDIFF(NOW(),MAX(updated_date))
FROM `authentication`
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),updated_date) > 20
GROUP by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance, further modify one of the other answers with

```
WHERE updated_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 20 DAY
```

and index `updated_date`.